# catch event when the field changes

Tags: javascript, events, plugins, action

I got a multiple fields with the same name class = "value_field". If the input is type date I want to execute one function but this type it's a plugin and don't catch the event "onchange" or "infocusout".

[image: Type date]

And the JS function to catch each event is:

```
$('body').on('focusout', '.value_field', function() { blablal }
```

How can I catch the event when the input it's filled by the plugin?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which plugin are you using. Can you send us the link?

Comment: I'm using this plugin: https://github.com/longbill/jquery-date-range-picker
Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code you used to initiate the plugin. I will tell you what changes you need to make in that. Its easy.!

Comment: I used this to configure the input id date_range with the plugin: $('#date_range').dateRangePicker(); Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Check the updated answer... The bottom two code blocks is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the `.js` of plugin and you should trigger `change`

```
.trigger('change');
```

where they are updating the value of the input field.

Then you can catch it by

```
$('.value_field').change(function() { 

    // Whatever

});
```

In your case, Initiate it like

```
$('#date_range').dateRangePicker(
{
    setValue: function(s)
        {
            this.value = s;
            $(this).trigger("change");
        }
}
);
```

and then catch it by

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#date_range").change(function(){
    console.log("Value Changed, New Value is "+$(this).val());
  });

});
```

Comment: Yes!! It work's sorry for answer late! Thanks you a lot!